# How to access object initialised in another PHPUnit test

Tags: php, phpunit

I have this code:

```
public function testFoo() {
    $this->object = newBar();
}
```

But later, e.g., in method `testAdd()`, `$this->object` is `null`. `testAdd` executes after `testFoo`.

Why does this happen, and is there any setUp-like method for whole test case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every test method is executed on a new instance of the test case class. There is indeed a setup method that is called before each test, and it's called [`setUp`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html).

```
public function setUp() {
    $this->object = newBar();
}

public function testFoo() {
    // use $this->object here
}

public function testBar() {
    // use $this->object here too, though it's a *different* instance of newBar
}
```

If you need to share state across all tests for a test case--often ill-advised--you can use the static `setUpBeforeClass` method.

```
public static function setUpBeforeClass() {
    self::$object = newBar();
}

public function testFoo() {
    // use self::$object here
}

public function testBar() {
    // use self::$object here too, same instance as above
}
```

Comment: I solve it in the similar way:

    protected function setUp() {
        if (!self::$object) {
            self::$object = new Foo();
        }
    }

Comment: @pinepain - That works of course, but using `setUp` to mimic `setUpBeforeClass` complicates the code unnecessarily.

Comment: Oh, i get it, thank you, i spent whole evening to find this method documentation.

Comment: No worries. While at first PHPUnit seems way more complicated than SimpleTest, it gets easier fairly quickly. It is patterned after JUnit and similar implementations so the knowledge will transfer, too.

Comment: I think that accessing in this way is not a good idea, in general. Probably the problem is in a wrong design. What do you think about Test Data Builders pattern to use in this situation?

Comment: The more you can isolate tests from each other, the less likely you are to have false positives and negatives. Each test should operate on new state wherever possible. Only when you have performance problems with your tests should you consider sharing state.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a question similar to this before here: [Why are symfony DOMCrawler objects not properly passed between dependent phpunit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311744/why-are-symfony-domcrawler-objects-not-properly-passed-between-dependent-phpunit).

Basically, some sort of `shutdown` method is called between tests unless you explicitly make them dependent, which is not advised. One option is to override the `setUp` method if there's something you want for each test though.

Comment: I found that __constructor is called for every test method. Probably i have to read manual one more time, but anyway it's a  strange behavior as for me (I migrated from SimpleTest).